# The names of the levels in a factor variable matter

Tags: r, nlme

I have fitted an lme model using a factor variable `studytreat`. It appears in the model in two places, as a fixed effect, and also to model heterogeneity in the residual variance so that each level of `studytreat` has its own variance. This is the model:

```
modelLME <- lme(logkp ~ studytreat, 
                random = ~ -1 + STUDY | ptno, 
                weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | studytreat))
```

I have a problem which doesn't fill me with confidence in lme! If I label the levels in studytreat as 11, 12, 21, 24 (in that order) then the function works fine. However, if I switch the numbers around to get `11, 21, 12, 42` then when I call `summary(modelLME)$apVar` I get the error message:

```
[1] "Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance"
```

Does anyone have any idea why this should make a difference?

Comment: Please provide the original factor variable and show the code you used to change the levels.

Comment: This post should also be rephrased as a question, along the lines of asking why it makes a difference.

Comment: Does the model that "works" really work, i.e. does it provide a solution with reasonable confidence intervals on the variances (what is `summary(modelLME)$apVar`) ? I can imagine that a just-barely-stable model could get tipped over the line to a not-quite-stable model by switching the structure ...

Comment: Ganesh: thanks, I have done that.

Comment: Sven: I create studytreat from two numerical variables 'STUDY' = 1 or 2 and 'pktrt' = 1,2 or 4, by studytreat = 10*STUDY + pktrt, then studytreat <- factor(studytreat). For the reversal the roles of 'STUDY' and 'pktrt' are switched.

Comment: Ben: I'm not sure what I should be looking for in summary(modelLME)$apVar to see if the model is unstable. I think it is quite close to being overparameterised so you might be right. However, I wouldn't have thought a relabelling should have any effect. I have noted since my original post that the order of the levels changes in the relabelling, which I suppose might count as a change in "structure". Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TomMorris Thanks for the information. Why did you change the factor?

Comment: Sven: When I wrote down the model I denoted the outcome y_ijk where j is treatment and k is study. I wanted the factor labels to be in the same order as the subscripts, i.e. treatment before study. It doesn't matter really but I thought the strange behaviour of nlme worth mentioning.